# Voyager keeps reverting database into my deployed version on production server

Tags: database, laravel, heroku, deployment, voyager

I deployed my Laravel application with Voyager admin panel into Heroku. When I add/edit/delete any product from dashboard, every change reverts after approx 30minutes after the update. There are no error message shown anywhere in my application and everything seems to be working just fine. I want to control my data from admin panel in production server, but I cannot fix this issue after googling for a week. What could've gone wrong that caused this issue? Any suggestions?